# Best Practice to organize measures in SSAS

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

Currently developing a SSAS Tabular model project in Visual Studio 2022.

I am trying to navigate how to best develop measures and organize them. There is a 'Display Folder' property that can be used to organize the measures into sub-folders.

The problem is the folders seem to only appear when the model is loaded through a client (i.e. PowerBI). How can we organize measures better within SSAS as we develop new measures?

Measures in SSAS:

[image]

Measures in PowerBI:

[image]

Is there not a way to put these folders to use within SSAS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The older practice was to create dummy DAX tables and create measures in the grid. You would go to the DAX Orders table or DAX Cost table and see all those measures together. The grid at the bottom is hard to organize though, so once the number of measures starts getting high, we just switched to using search from the Tabular Model Explorer to find measures in Visual Studio.

The more important practice is a good naming convention for measures. Mostly you want to be consistent, and put modifiers at the end of the name and in a consistent order.

Here's an example from an accounting model for **Period Cost**. Because they use these in reports where short labels are preferred, they are in a folder of "Period Cost" and the names are abbreviated to **PC**, and all the modifiers are abbreviated too.

Start with a base name:

- **PC** = base measure for actual Period Cost
- **PC BP** = base measure for **Business Plan** values for Period Cost, set at the beginning of the year.
- **PC Fcst** = base measure for the rolling **Forecast** of Period Cost

Add time dimension:

- PC **FY** = Full year
- PC BP **PM** = Prior month
- PC Fcst **PY** = Prior year

Year to Date is always added at the end:

- PC **YTD**
- PC *PY* **YTD**
- PC BP **YTD**
- PC Fcst **YTD**

Then you can search better:

- **PC** finds them all
- **PC BP** finds all the Business Plan measures for Period Cost
- **PC Fcst** finds all the Forecast measures for Period Cost

Comment: Suggest for reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/calculation-groups?view=sql-analysis-services-2022